# How do I solve this Linear Algebra question?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, gram-schmidt

Let $P_2$ be the vector space of all polynomial functions of degree at most two from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and let $f_0,f_1,f_1: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the functions given by $$f_0(x)=1, \ f_1(x)=x, \ f_2(x)=x^2$$

a) Show that $B =(f_0,f_1,f_2)$ is an ordered basis of $P_2$.

b) Show that the function $T: P_2 ↦ P_2$ given by

$$T(f)(x)=f(x+1), \ \ x \in \mathbb{R}$$

is a linear transformation.

c) Find the matrix $A^{B,B}_T$.

Comment: In mathematics, when in doubt, write out the definitions.  In general, when you post a question you need to tell us what work you have done, what you have tried, and where you are stuck, so we don't waste time explaining things you already know or talking over your head.

Comment: I don't understand how the question is phrased, in the sense that I dont know how these functions would ever form a basis, let alone an ordered basis of the given vector space or even how part b would lead to a linear transformation as I'm not sure how to express T(f)(x) in the vector space.

Comment: @hihihi1029 As an informal explanation: every polynomial function of degree at most $2$ can be written in the form $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$. To put it another way, every element $f$ can be written in the form $f = a f_2 + bf_1 + cf_0$ for some scalars $a,b,c \in \Bbb R$ (in other words, the functions $f_0,f_1,f_2$ span $P_2$). On the other hand, these functions are "non-redundant" in the sense that we can only have 
$$
a_0 f_0 + a_1 f_1 + a_2 f_2 = b_0 f_0 + b_1 f_1 + b_2 f_2
$$
if $a_0 = b_0, a_1=b_1, a_2 = b_2$. Because both of these conditions hold, the set is a basis

Comment: @hihihi1029 The fact that the set forms an "ordered basis" just means that we care about the order; there's nothing that you need to show for that. For instance, $(f_1,f_0,f_2)$ and $(f_0,f_1,f_2)$ are different "ordered bases" even though we used the same set of functions (i.e. they are equal as "unordered bases/sets".

Comment: @hihihi1029 As for the formal answer to part a) of this question, what you need to do is show that the functions satisfy the properties in the definition of a basis, which you should look up either in your notes or in your textbook. As the first comment indicates, answering this question really amounts to applying a definition without much further thought.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Hmm. That does make sense. However, the answer provided to me utilised the Gram Schmdit Method to prove this. Does the Gram Schmdit Method show bases are ordered or does it simply show linear independence, which is one of the conditions for that being a base?

Comment: @hihihi1029 First of all, that information about the answer you were given could have been useful context to include with your question. Consider doing this next time; see [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for more details about what you could include. Second, there is no reason to use the Gram Schmidt process for the first two parts of this problem. The use of an inner product does provide an alternative approach to part (c), but in my opinion that isn't worth it.

Comment: @hihihi1029 Yes, the Gram Schmidt method does technically give you a way to show that the three functions are linearly independent. However, there is a simpler approach: we only need to use the fact that $f(x) = c_0 + c_1 x + c_2 x^2$ can only be the zero function if all the coefficients are zero.

Comment: @hihihi1029 If we want to show that $f = 0$ implies that the coefficients are zero, we can use the fact that $f = 0$ implies that its first and second derivatives are equal to zero (for all inputs $x$).